# Life gain against fatal spell damage

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was recently in the following situation. I had an untapped [sunscorch regent](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=sunscorch%20regent) and 5 life. It was my opponents turn and he cast [Beacon of destruction](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Beacon%20of%20destruction).

Would I have died or would I have 1 life remaining.

Comment: Just a note that whether Sunscorch Regent is tapped or not makes no difference here.

Comment: Would the life gain be triggered again if he were to cast another spell?

Comment: Yes, "Whenever X happens" means "every time that X happens"; no limit on how many.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would have 1 life remaining. Action order:

- Opponent casts Beacon of Destruction, it goes on stack.
- Sunscorch Regent triggers, it goes on stack.

If both players pass, the stack starts resolving top to bottom. First you gain 1 life and put a counter on Regent. You now have 6 life. Next, Beacon resolves, you are dealt 5 damage and now have 1 life.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the last to trigger is the first to resolve. Your opponent will have played a spell which will trigger your dragons ability and then when things start resolving you will gain a life and put a counter on before the spell that triggered your dragon gets a chance to resolve.

Comment: "Remember that the last to trigger is the first to resolve." This isn't exactly true... the last trigger to be put on the stack is the first to resolve. Not the same as the last to trigger.

Comment: First in last out.

Comment: Right, but I'm saying that "first in" refers to when the ability was put on the stack, which is different then when it triggers.